# Load images from a specific domain in typo3

Tags: typo3

For performance I want to be able to load images in typo3temp/pics and uploads/pics/ from another domain.  I can see that I can configure this through config.absRefPrefix but this also applies to anchor tags as well.  Is this possible in typo3?  I have also done a bit of research about config.prefixLocalAnchors which I can't get to work on my installation.  And in any case config.absRefPrefix seems to override this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look if any of those extensions are helpful in your case:
https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/?tx_terfe_pi1%5Bview%5D=search&no_cache=1&tx_terfe_pi1%5Bsword%5D=cdn

Comment: Is this still necessary in TYPO3 6.x? Or can FAL do that job by itself for images? And by the way: does the "cookie free domain" recommendation (which comes from YSlow) really make sense?

Comment: Cookie free domain only makes sense for high traffic sites and a large amount of mobile users. The effect is really little and there is so much more that you can optimize before doing that. I suggest to ignore it until it becomes pressing.